# VueJS with Large Forms

Tags: forms, binding, model, vue.js

I have a huge form with 20+ fields. i feel so much redundancy on the code i write now. What is the best way ?

```
<script>
new Vue({
    data : {
        user : {
            first_name : "",
            last_name : "",
            username : "",
            and 20+.........
        }
    }
});
</script>

<form>
    <input name="first_name" v-model="first_name">
    <input name="last_name" v-model="last_name">
    <input name="username" v-model="username">
    and 20+......... input fields
</form>
```

i feel something like this would be nice. the user object will be created dynamically.. is this possible ?

```
<script>
new Vue({
    data : {
        user :  Object
    }
});
</script>

<form v-model="user">
    <input name="first_name">
    <input name="last_name">
    <input name="username">
    and 20+......... input fields
</form>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: In principle you could make a custom directive, but it would need to be able to bind `v-model` to all the inputs, and Vue doesn't seem to provide for a way to programmatically bind directives.

Comment: You can use my module vue-formation :)

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I've updated my answer for Vue 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Completely Redone in Vue 2**

Your approach is the reverse of the usual Vue approach, in that you want to lay out your data structure in the view and have Vue pick it up, rather than laying it out in the data and having Vue render it. I can see how that would be desirable if you have a customized layout you want to achieve.

Unconventional needs require unconventional solutions, so this approach is unconventional. In particular, it is not generally recommended that a child component modify data in a parent.

That said, the approach is to create a component that will accept the form inputs as a slot and the parent object as a prop. In `mounted`, it gets all the `input` fields with `name` attributes and

1. Creates the member in the parent object, using `$set`
2. Sets a watch on the newly-created member
3. Adds an `input` event listener to complete the two-way binding

You would probably want to add more props to the component, to make the form itself more versatile, but this gives you the functionality you're looking for.

```js
Vue.component('autoBindingForm', {
  template: '<form><slot></slot></form>',
  props: ['createIn'],
  mounted() {
    const inputs = this.$el.querySelectorAll('input[name]');

    for (const i of inputs) {
      this.$set(this.createIn, i.name, i.value);
      this.$watch(`createIn.${i.name}`, (newVal, oldVal) => {
        i.value = newVal;
      });
      i.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        this.createIn[i.name] = i.value;
      });
    }
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {}
  }
});

// Testing that binding works both ways
setTimeout(() => {
  vm.user.last_name = 'Set it';
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <auto-binding-form :create-in="user">
    <input name="first_name" value="hi">
    <input name="last_name">
    <input name="username">
    <div>{{Object.keys(user)}}</div>
    <div>{{Object.values(user)}}</div>
  </auto-binding-form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
data: {
  fields: { name: {v:''}, surname: {v:''}, ... }
}
```

and

```
<input v-for="(val, prop) in fields" :name="prop" v-model="val.v" />
```

?

https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/dhdxqwjv/1/

Comment: This is the reverse of what the poster asked for. Instead of the data creating the DOM, he wants the DOM to create the data.